# How can I translate MISSING and INTNX functions (in SAS) to snowflake?

Tags: sql, sas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, proc

So I've been trying to figure out a way to translate a chunk of code on SAS to snowflake where the SAS model is using a CASE statement followed by some MISSING and INTNX functions, but I just can't find a solution for the MISSING one. I've tried using IFF, IFNULL, IS NULL, but when executing the code, errors show up.

This is part of the code:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE GRIDWORK.DAYS_CALC AS 
SELECT t1.POLICY_NBR, 
      t1.POLICY_EFCTV_DT, 
      t1.CNTRCT_STTS_CD,
      t2.TRANS_TYP_CD AS CANCEL_CD,
      t2.POST_DT AS CANCEL_POST,
      t2.EFCTV_DT AS CANCEL_EFF,
      t1.BKD_DT,
      (CASE
      WHEN BAND(t1.CNTRCT_STTS_CD = 'C', MISSING(t2.EFCTV_DT) = 1)
      THEN 0
      WHEN t1.POLICY_EFCTV_DT > t1.BKD_DT
      THEN CASE
      WHEN MISSING(t2.EFCTV_DT) = 1
      THEN INTNX("MONTH", t1.BKD_DT, 1, "B") - t1.POLICY_EFCTV_DT
```

About the INTNX function, I've used DATEADD but I haven't find a way to add the alignment argument, is there a way to do it?
If anyone could give me a hand on this, I would be very happy!!

Comment: it would help to get faster and better response, if you can provide a chunked down version of the issue with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: `...but when executing the code, errors show up.` What are the errors? If the MISSING function is checking whether or not a column exists, this is one thing. If it's just checking whether or not an existing column has a blank field, that's a simpler matter to address.

Comment: `missing()` in SAS checks whether a numeric or character column is null or not. 1 if it is, 0 if it is not. Missing values in SAS are denoted by `.` for numeric variables and a space (blank) for characters.

Comment: Yep, syntax says MISSING( numeric-expression | character-expression), what I don’t understand on the code Is MISSING(t2.EFCTV_DT) **= 1**. As far as I understand, if there’s any missing value on the EFCTV_DT column, function would return 0 or 1. But then why writing “=1”?

Comment: I'm confused about the SAS `MISSING` function. Is it checking the expression passed into the function only? Or is it checking if any value is missing in the column, top to bottom? If it's just a matter of checking the input expression and comparing it to `.` for numeric or ` ` (space) for string, this would be a fairly simple overloaded SQL UDF.

Comment: It seems like it's a per row, and almost the equiv of a regex for "goodness" which could be replaced with a REGEXP_COUNT.

Comment: The MISSING() function returns the result of testing whether the argument is missing or not.  For numeric variables (like a DATE value) SAS has 28 distinct missing values and MISSING() will return TRUE when the value is any of them. Since boolean expressions in SAS evaluate to 1 when TRUE and 0 when FALSE adding the `=1` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are three parts to translating:

```
INTNX("MONTH", t1.BKD_DT, 1, "B") - t1.POLICY_EFCTV_DT
```

the first two are the translation of the [INTNX](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm) where is adding one month and returning the begin of the month. Which can be done as a "trunc then add" or a "add then trunc", via [DATEADD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html), & [DATE_TRUNC](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html)

```
SELECT 
    to_date(column1) as d
    ,dateadd(month,1,d) as t
    ,date_trunc('month', t) as INTNX
FROM VALUES
('2022-07-12'),
('2022-01-30'),
('2022-02-01'),
('2022-06-01');
```

| D | T | INTNX |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-12 | 2022-08-12 | 2022-08-01 |
| 2022-01-30 | 2022-02-28 | 2022-02-01 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-01 |
| 2022-06-01 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-07-01 |

then there is the difference in dates, that appears to be the number of days.

so with [DATEDIFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/datediff.html) the line becomes:

```
datediff('day', date_trunc('month', dateadd(month,1,t1.BKD_DT)), t1.POLICY_EFCTV_DT ) as date_sub
```

Then there is the [MISSING](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p06ybg84o0asa4n17l9ieauk58hb.htm), which appears to be a value tests which should be possible to solve via [REGEXP_COUNT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_count.html) if you provide the correct pattern

Comment: The SQL way to reference missing values is the keyword `NULL`.  So the test  `WHEN (t2.EFCTV_DT is null)` should work fine.

Comment: if also checks for "unwanted tokens" `A numeric expression is considered missing if it evaluates to a numeric missing value: ., ._, .A, ..., .Z.`